# Prevent Visual Studio Server Explorer from auto-populating

Tags: visual-studio, ide, web-config, visual-studio-2015, server-explorer

I am running into a frustrating issue with Visual Studio in which every time I open or refresh a solution, Visual Studio locks up for about 30 seconds and then I am met with this error

[image: Visual Studio error]

This happens about 10 times, so it takes about five minutes to get a working instance of Visual Studio.

I eventually traced this to entries in Server Explorer to which I don't have access. These seem to be auto-populated from connection string entries in various Web.config files throughout the solution. If I comment out the connection strings, the solution loads fine. But this is not an ideal solution because I don't want to commit these changes to source control.

Is there a way to stop this auto-population of Server Explorer? I don't remember this ever happening in previous version of Visual Studio, so maybe it's new in 2015?